# Problem with Microsoft Access Database linking to a SharePoint list?

Tags: list, microsoft-access

I have a few SharePoint lists as the back end to several different Access Databases - each used by different people for different tasks so different queries and different forms as required.

One particular SharePoint List has 5858 entries on the website 
and the same in the linked table in one of my Access Databases.

BUT in another Access Database the linked table to the SAME SharePoint list has only 30 entries!!!!

No amount of unlinking & relinking this table has returned the missing data, nor compacting/reparing the database

All the other linked SharePoint Lists in the same Access database seem to be working fine.

Has anyone any ideas on how to fix the broken link?
Ta

phil

Comment: Maybe there's a threshold of maximum 30 entries to be loaded? Or the connection string is limited to this count of elements? Are there any similarities in the elements; like all are created within the last 5 days or have the same category/metadata?

Comment: The 30 entries seem to be the oldest 30, but this is not an issue for the same linked list in a very similar database

Comment: Provide us connections strings and screenshots for better understanding, are there different permissions? Isn't any filter in the data query?

Comment: Hi sorry i don't know how to add a screenshot here...
but there are no different permissions, nor any filters. 

It is simply the same linked share-point list opened in two separate access databases both logged into share-point using the same user account and login details.

one shows 30 entries the other 5858 entries.